# GNU Octave: .csl file not recgnized

Tags: class, octave, gnu

I have never used Octave before this (I have used Matlab), but I installed GNU Octave because I wanted to use one of the repository/package that was written in GNU Octave. That repository has files with extension `.csl`, which are called within the `.m` files (main scripts) without their extension. For example, a file named `foo.csl` is called like a function `foo()` within the main script. However, when I run the main script (`.m` file that calls the `.csl` file as a function) it throws an error saying that the function `foo()` is undefined. The file `foo.csl` begins as following:

```
class foo
% Definition about the class foo

public x
public y
public z
```

I searched for `.csl` file extensions associated with GNU Octave, but I could not find anything helpful. I am using the latest version of GNU Octave on Windows 10.

Comment: Why don't you mention the "one of the repository/package that was written in GNU Octave" and provide a link?

Comment: I can't, and it's not necessary here. Hope that helps.

Comment: nope, this doesn't help

Comment: @user11 neither matlab nor octave use the `class` keyword to define a class in the manner shown above. So this is not valid matlab / octave code. Nor is the `.csl` extension anything to do with matlab / octave. My guess is that this represents bespoke code that is transformed to valid matlab / octave code or generally dealt with internally by whatever package you are attempting to use. So unfortunately, Andy is right: without specific information there's not much anyone could do to help you (unless they happen to have come across the specific package you're referring to by chance).

Comment: The only thing I can think of that may be going on is that those files are just 'decorative' to inform you, the user, about the class structure, and the real class definitions are actually sitting in a folder called `@foo` somewhere in your path. In which case, if you have neglected to add `@foo` to the path, you'll get an error that `foo` (i.e. the constructor) is undefined.

Comment: How about if I give you the link to couple of files, including the `.cls` and the `.m` file that's calling the function name with `.cls`extension? Would that be sufficient?

Comment: @user11 sure, if you'd like. Btw, note that neither I nor Andy receive a notification for this comment. I only spotted this comment because I just randomly remembered and happened to check this post to see if someone else had commented anything. When you want to notify someone specifically, use the "@username" syntax, like I did here. (the only person who gets notified automatically without the need for further tagging, is the person who posts the question / answer to which one is commenting)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Thanks. You can find the two files [here](https://ufile.io/jq5e7) and [here](https://ufile.io/5wq34).

Comment: @user11 any luck / comments / updates?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Please see my comment under your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at your files.

The *bad* news is, as I've said in the comments, the `.csl` file is not valid matlab / octave code. This leads me to believe that one of the following might be happening:

- The `.csl` file is "processed" elsewhere to produce an *actual* matlab / octave compatible class
- The `.csl` file is simply a pseudo-code "specification", and the *actual* matlab / octave class is provided elsewhere, and you're supposed to 'load' it somehow.
- This was part of an assignment, where whoever gave you this code was expected to convert the `.csl` file into appropriate matlab / octave code.
- Whoever wrote this doesn't know matlab and this is just plain wrong code.

The *good* news is that this is very easy to translate into working code. Since your desired `RecDomain` "class" is essentially a simple class with exclusively public fields and no methods, it can be straightforwardly replaced by a simple `struct`. Meaning you can replace the entire `RecDomain.csl` file with the following:

```
%%% in file RecDomain.m

function Out = RecDomain (varargin)
%RecDomain() creates a domain with given parameters.
%RecDomain(d) creates a domain copy.  

  switch nargin 
     case 1 % a struct was given as input
        Out  = varargin{1};

     case 3 % individual Dx, Dy, Dz arguments were given as input
        Out.Dx = varargin{1};
        Out.Dy = varargin{2};
        Out.Dz = varargin{3};

     otherwise 
        error('Wrong RecDomain constructor.\n');
  endswitch
endfunction
```

and then your `model1.m` script will work as is.

<sub>PS. (obviously the above is oversimplified and has no input checking / assertions etc, but you get the picture).</sub>

---

If this was a contrived simple example and your actual `.csl` files are more complex, then you'll have to convert them into proper octave classes yourself based on that `.csl` "specification", which is beyond the scope of this answer. Octave provides some limited support for [the *new* matlab object-oriented style using the `classdef` keyword](http://ubcmatlabguide.github.io/html/objectOriented.html) if you'd like to try that, but for the most part octave implements object-orientation using [matlab's *old* (pre-2008) style](https://ubcmatlabguide.github.io/html/objectOrientedOldStyle.html). See here for the respective official documentation entries: [[matlab (new syntax)]](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) / [[octave (old syntax)]](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Object-Oriented-Programming.html#Object-Oriented-Programming)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I changed some other `.csl` files to functions as suggested, but I was not able to correctly change one file [Particle.csl](https://ufile.io/hkarv) to an appropriate function because it contains some nested functions that are called as a field of the main output (e.g. `ptl.transport()`) as shown in [model1.m](https://ufile.io/bx2p2) file. Could you help with how to modify `Particle.csl` to an appropriate function so it can be called as shown in `model1.m`?

Comment: Alas, like I said, this is not valid matlab code. You need to figure out what's going on instead. Ask the package maintainer what these .csl files represent. In theory, if these were valid functions, you could just save them individually in a file and create another field in your 'object' struct and assign it a handle to that function. But the "functions" here are broken to begin with, they have undefined arguments, calls to other inexistent functions etc. So in this case even if you "translate" this to a struct, you're missing information that relates to their function.